# Which block method should be used for preparing data

Tags: blocks

In a standard template block i.e. extends `Mage_Core_Block_Template`, which method should be used for preparing required block data?

Is it beforeToHtml? or some other?

---

Im looking to find the most accepted way to load the block with the required data for it to render correctly.  For example if the block needs a collection or some other model of data, should this be loaded in the beforeToHtml method or  prepareLayout etc etc.

Comment: Can you explain a bit what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have edited the question to explain further

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually a good question.
In the core there are some blocks that use `_beforeToHtml` to prepare the data. See for example `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List`, `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Crosssell` and a lot of admin blocks.
There are also blocks that use the `__construct` method to process some data. See `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options`, `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart` and again a lot of admin blocks.
Some of them use `_toHtml` to process data. See `Mage_Rss_Block_Catalog_New`, `Mage_Sales_Block_Order_Email_Items_Order_Grouped`.

My vote goes for... neither.
I like using lazy loading. So in my custom blocks I implement methods that process data only when needed. Let's take your example. "The block needs a collection."
I create the method

```
public function getSomeCollection(){
    if (!$this->hasData('_some_collection')){
        $someCollection = 'Magic happens here';
        $this->setData('_some_collection', $someCollection);
    }
    return $this->getData('_some_collection')
}
```

This way I'm sure that my collection is loaded only when calling it the first time. The result is cached in the block `_data` member so it's not processed twice if called twice.
So I call this method in the phtml file when needed.

The `_` in the front of `_some_collection` is there so I'm sure that you cannot call `setSomeCollection`. If you don't need this restriction you can skip the underscore.